# Docker volume mapping file corruption when filesystem is xfs and storage driver is overlay

Tags: docker

when I volume mapping in Docker 1.13.0, some file is corrupted.

In docker container, when "ls -l" the folder, it displayed like this:

"?????????? ? ?    ?     ?            ? file_corrpted_and_cant_access.conf"

and can't edit it or delete it.
it just show "No such file or directory".
I think it can't link file inode and path.

how to fix it?

**Additional information**

after volume mapping, I soft link volume mapping folder inside docker container.

`docker run --privileged -d -v /opt/volume_mapping_folder/:/inside_container/inside_folder --restart=always testcontainer`

and insde docker container I soft link folder

`docker -it testcontainer /bin/bash`
`ln -s /inside_container/inside_folder /opt/appFolder`
`touch /opt/appFolder/file_corrpted_and_cant_access.conf`

**Output of `docker info`:**

`Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 5.671 GiB
ID: 2D2E:73MA:BJQ3:WQAJ:BR3W:TYF5:F3MQ:E7S3:KZGV:A64K:ASZK:UEXE
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is is related xfs filesystem with overlay mode.

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27358

the solution is one of these.

1. xfs partitions need to be formatted with ftype set to 1
2. use ext4 filesystem instead of xfs
3. setting docker Storage Driver to 'devicemapper'

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar problem today using Docker 1.13.0 running a CentOS image on a RHEL 7.3 system. Files in my containers root filesystem were acting *odd*. For example, I would try to delete a file but it would not be removed from the filesystem and display the same '?' you posted when running 'ls'. I also had problems trying to change ownership of files. Anyway, my guess is Docker 1.13.0 changed the default Storage Driver to *overlay* when in the past (Docker 1.12.5) it was *devicemapper*. I changed the default back to *devicemapper* and the problems went away.

I am not a Docker or Linux Filesystem expert and I am not sure if the change to overlay as a default was intentional.

Comment: thx, after change storage driver to devicemapper, the problems went away.